# Daisy chaining a lot of networking devices, is this a good idea?

Tags: networking, home-networking, switch

I know a little about networking, but I wouldn't even call myself a novice... so of course I am running CAT6a through my house. I would like to know if my plan makes any sense. I have a fiber modem that requires PPOE login and VLAN tagging 201, I already had a Google WiFi mesh network and some Netgear switches so I am trying to reuse as much as possible. But Google WiFi doesn't support the VLAN tagging so I bought a stand alone wired router Ubiquiti ER4. My fiber modem is in a structured media center in my garage, I am planning on putting the router there along with a 8 port managed switch.

I was going to do a 10 foot run of two cables to a bedroom from the garage that would connect the router to the first WiFI AP and from that AP and have the AP's network controlling everything in the house. The AP would plug into an 8 port unmanageable switch in that bedroom, and that switch would then plugin to the second run back down to the garage and into a basic "smart managed" switch. There is an 8 port patch panel in the garage where the garage switch will hook up all the runs in the house. I need the switch in the bedroom as well since I have 5 electronics that need hardwire connections.

I guess my main concern is it ok to have this daisy chain of equipment. Fiber modem -> Router -> Google WiFi mesh unit -> unmanaged switch -> managed switch -> Google WiFi mesh units / other electronics like PS4, etc... Should I reverse the switches? What if I have a third 5 port switch at the end?

Comment: well, you want to keep it as simple as possible, and i would attempt to connect only switches together (use the wifi devices as APs just connected to the switches, not connecting them), but the general idea is fine if thats what you have to work with. it might be suboptimal, but we can;t all have enterprise networks in our home.

Comment: If you're installing Ethernet outlets in the walls, you don't need mesh. Just use the Google Wifi units as simple APs, each plugged into the Ethernet LAN. If any room needs more than one device, put an unmanaged switch in that room and connect all your wired devices (including the Google Wifi AP for that room) into it. I don't see any good reason to go directly from the router to one Google Wifi AP, then back down to a switch to the rest of the home LAN. If you're doing that, you're probably running that Google Wifi as a router, meaning you're doing double NAT accidentally, which isn't ideal.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, based off these I think I'll plug the router into the managed switch in the garage and then connect that switch to all the runs and use the Google WiFi units as APs.